# Getting Euclidian distance from Weka's Java API

Tags: java, exception, machine-learning, nullpointerexception, weka

I'm using Weka Machine learning library's Java API...

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two instances using the EuclidianDistance class:

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/EuclideanDistance.html

I have this code:

```
      EuclideanDistance ed = new EuclideanDistance(finalInst);
      double dist;

      dist = ed.distance(finalInst.firstInstance(),finalInst.lastInstance());
```

`finalInst` is a valid Instances object that contains valid Instance objects...

Here's what the first and last instance are when you use `System.out.println`:

```
finalInst.firstInstance():

?,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

finalInst.lastInstance():

?,?,?,?,1,1,?,1,?,1,?,?,1,?,?,?,?,?,1
```

But then when I run the code, it returns a null pointer exception...

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: there's no stack trace it's a caught exception

Comment: You have to see the error and show it to us for this to make sense. Who is throwing the error? What's the method signature to ed.distance?

Comment: the function works fine with my data set! provide some detail so that it is replicable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got two practical suggestions:

1) Dig in WEKA's code. It's open-source, so you can actually add the source to your Eclipse project and browse the relevant functions with F3 (I do hope you're using Eclipse or some other reasonable IDE).

2) Implement your own Euclidean distance. It's really simple. Here, I've even done it for you:

```
public double distance(List<Double> instance1, List<Double> instance2) {
    double dist = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < instance1.size(); i++) {
        double x = instance1.get(i);
        double y = instance2.get(i);

        if (Double.isNaN(x) || Double.isNaN(y)) {
            continue; // Mark missing attributes ('?') as NaN.
        }

        dist += (x-y)*(x-y);
    }

    return Math.sqrt(dist);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but:
You have to pass an Instances (that usually comes from an ARFF file) object to the EuclideanDistance constructor.
Re-implementing the wheel usually leads to problems in the future.
For example, attributes can be nominal.